# New Kibana reposting job goes in Pending instead of Processing

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Using **ELKStack 7.12.1**, After deleting pending jobs from Kibana reposting using the below api,

```
POST /.reporting*/_delete_by_query
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must_not": {
                "exists": {
                    "field": "completed_at"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

all my new cvs export reposting job goes into pending state for some time then it goes in processing, is this query takes time after sending the 200 response code or the job just removed from the Kibana Reposting UI and still running the background till all 3 attempts fails.